# select_for_update doesn't prevent race conditions in PostgreSQL, while F expression does

Tags: python, django, postgresql, unit-testing, race-condition

I have a business model:

```py
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import F
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.response import Response

from business.models.abstract import Entity
from business.models.credit_history import CreditHistory


class Business(Entity):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=160)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=120, unique=True)
    credit = models.PositiveBigIntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.slug} - {self.title} - {self.credit}"

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            self.slug = self.slug or slugify(self.title)

        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def increase_credit(self, phone, amount):
        try:
            amount = int(amount)
        except ValueError:
            return Response({"message": "Amount must be a positive integer"}, status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        if amount <= 0:
            return Response({"message": "Amount must be a positive integer."}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        if amount > self.credit:
            return Response({"message": "Business doesn't have enough credit."}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        # self.credit = F("credit") - amount
        self.credit -= amount
        self.save()

        CreditHistory.objects.create(
            chargor=self.slug,
            chargee=phone,
            amount=amount,
        )

        return Response({"message": "Successfully charged user."}, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

And then I wrote a test to check for race conditions:

```py
from django.test import TransactionTestCase
from rest_framework.test import APIClient

from business.models.business import Business
from business.tests.increase_credit import IncreaseCredit

import before_after


class TestCreditHistory(TransactionTestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.client = APIClient()

        self.business1 = Business.objects.create(
            title="business 1",
        )
        self.business2 = Business.objects.create(
            title="business 2",
        )
        self.business3 = Business.objects.create(
            title="business 3",
        )

        self.businesses = [self.business1, self.business2, self.business3]


    def test_total_charged_for_race_condition(self):
        obj = IncreaseCredit(1_000_000)

        def after_function(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self.increase(
                "+989120000002",
                200_000,
            )

        with before_after.after(
            "business.tests.increase_credit.IncreaseCredit.get_business",
            after_function,
        ):
            credit, function_calls = obj.increase(
                "+989120000001",
                100_000,
            )
            
            self.assertEqual(function_calls, 2)
            self.assertEqual(credit, 700_000)
```

And the `business.tests.increase_credit.py` file is as follows:

```py
from django.db import transaction

from business.models.business import Business
from business.models.credit_history import CreditHistory

import random
import string


class IncreaseCredit:
    def __init__(self, amount):
        # random_title = ''.join(
        #     random.SystemRandom().choice(
        #         string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits
        #         ) for _ in range(30)
        # )

        self.business = Business.objects.create(
            title="title",
        )

        CreditHistory.objects.create(
            chargee=self.business.slug,
            amount=amount,
        )

        self.increase_function_calls = 0

    def get_business(self, slug):
        business = Business.objects.select_for_update()
        print(business.query)
        return business.get(slug=slug)

    @transaction.atomic
    def increase(self, phone, amount):
        self.increase_function_calls += 1
        business = self.get_business("title")
        business.increase_credit(
            phone,
            amount,
        )
        business.refresh_from_db()
        return business.credit, self.increase_function_calls
```

Running the test, the `get_business` method prints this query:

```sql
SELECT "business_business"."id", "business_business"."created_at", "business_business"."updated_at", "business_business"."title", "business_business"."slug", "business_business"."credit" FROM "business_business" FOR UPDATE
```

So I can see that the database does support low-level locking and I *can* use `select_for_update`. But the test fails at assertion:

```py
FAIL: test_total_charged_for_race_condition (business.tests.test_credit_history.TestCreditHistory)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/amir/Code/tabdeal/business/tests/test_credit_history.py", line 110, in test_total_charged_for_race_condition
    self.assertEqual(credit, 700_000)
AssertionError: 900000 != 700000
```

Now if I change the `increase_credit` method in the `Business` model to use `F()` expressions (by uncommenting the line `# self.credit = F("credit") - amount`) and remove the `select_for_update` from `business.tests.increase_credit.py`, the test passes. So why doesn't `select_for_update` work here?